# HTML and CSS file not linking

Tags: html, css

I'm guessing the HTML and CSS file aren't linking for some reason.
It's such a simple yet frustrating issue. I've checked spelling, folders etc.
The css file also appears in the sources tab on the inspect element section in google chrome.

HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <title>Home Page</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

</head>

<body>

  <h1>CMP- Climate Monitoring People</h1>

<div class="Menu">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">About Us</a>
  <a href="#">Chapters</a>
  <a href="#">Contact Us</a>

</div>

    </body>


</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
.nav {
  background: #fff;
  margin-left: -38px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav a{
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.nav a:hover{
  background: #ddd;
  color: blue;

}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: let's try: `<link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: You used `.Menu` in your html, and `.nav` in css.

Comment: I think it has linked correctly you can change body color to test if css is applying.

Comment: No difference when trying <link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

@SatoTakeru Didn't even realise that, thanks for spotting it, changed it and ran it again, did not work unfortunately.

Tried that too, still no progress

Comment: The comment of Sato gives you the answer. I would anyway suggest you to set your nav bar into a `<nav>` element and not `div`; Because this is the way and you wont need to specify a class and you could set your css directly on element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue comes from the class you're targeting in your CSS.
It currently doesn't exist in your HTML.
Just change `class="Menu"` to `class="nav"` and it will work.

```css
.nav {
  background: #fff;
  margin-left: -16px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav a{
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.nav a:hover{
  background: #ddd;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <title>Home Page</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

</head>

<body>

  <h1>CMP- Climate Monitoring People</h1>

  <div class="nav">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">About Us</a>
    <a href="#">Chapters</a>
    <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The above worked. But I have to have it named 'nav' as with Menu it does not work, which isn't an issue to be honest.

But upon adding the following to the css file no change happens
`h1{
  background-color: yellow;
}`

Comment: The best is still to set the whole block into a `nav` element instead of this ugly `div.nav`.

Answer (score 0):

in your css file you are trying to use class selector with name nav which does not exists as you have declared class name as Menu.So your Code should be like as shown below:

```
.Menu {
    background: #fff;
    margin-left: -38px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .Menu a{
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 1.7em;
    display: block;
    float: left;
  }
  
  .Menu a:hover{
    background: #ddd;
    color: blue;
  
  }
```